# Using API's with PHP

Tags: api

Please help..

I am trying to use Nutritionix API to allow the user to search the database for a food and enter the amount they consumed. My website should then calculate the calories. Once I understand it a little I should be able to continue myself but I am really not sure..on the Nutritionix website they have this example..

```
curl -XPOST https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
 "appId":"APP_ID",
 "appKey":"APP_KEY",
 "query":"Cookies `n Cream"
}
'
```

I have the APP_ID and APP_KEY. I need to put this code in a php file in some sort of if statement..can someone please give me a quick example of how I would write this into a php file for it to work? At the moment I am literally copying and pasting that into the PHP file to try get some idea and its giving an error at https..any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example they are giving is for requesting their API using cURL in the command-line. You can try that too.

In PHP you can also use cURL. You could try something like this:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        "appId=id&appKey=key&query=milk");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

print_r($response);
?>
```

You should google cURL and PHP and read up on that.

Comment: Thank you! Ok I understand a bit more now, I was really confused as I have never even heard of cURL before today. I tried your code above and although I get no errors, the results of the search don't appear either. Any ideas? But I am looking up how cURL and PHP now so I'm sure I'll figure it out. Thanks again.

Comment: Never mind, that code worked once I changed it to "http" as I am using a local machine. Thanks!!